# symfony 2.4 cookies does not set

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use ESS\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use ESS\UserBundle\Form\UserType;
use ESS\UserBundle\Form\UserEdit;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

        $user_cookie = new Cookie('user','admin',12000); 
                $code_cookie = new Cookie('ccode','1234',12000);
                $response = new Response();
                $response->headers->setCookie($user_cookie);
                $response->headers->setCookie($code_cookie);
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    exit;
```

I have used this code to set cookie. But, it is not set. Cannot figure it out why ??

Cookie is enabled on my browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to test your code with https://github.com/oodle/KrumoBundle
It is the best for debug object elements like a cookie.

I agree with Tomasz, "object your cookie should be set but in next request to server." part of the answer. But You should use $response->sendHeaders(); instead of return operation.
I got clean white page with return $response;

**Code:**

```
$user_cookie = new Cookie('user','admin',12000); 
$code_cookie = new Cookie('ccode','1234',12000);
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie($user_cookie);
$response->headers->setCookie($code_cookie);
$response->sendHeaders();
```

// After it you can return to action related twig or redirect somewhere.

Comment: $response->sendHeaders(); must be called after setCookie()

Answer (score 0):

In this code your `$_COOKIE` won't be set because it's set when response is sent back to user.
So, after executing your code and returning `Response` object your cookie should be set but in **next** request to server.

```
$user_cookie = new Cookie('user','admin',12000); 
$code_cookie = new Cookie('ccode','1234',12000);
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie($user_cookie);
$response->headers->setCookie($code_cookie);
return $response;
```